# In R - generate pairwise data.frame from all rows in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have a data.frame called `df` with a 8 million observations on 4 columns:

```
name <- c("Pablo", "Christina", "Steve", "Diego", "Ali", "Brit", "Ruth", "Mia", "David", "Dylan")
year <- seq(2000, 2009, 1)
v1 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
v2 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(year, v1)

> df
        name year v1 v2
1      Pablo 2000  2  9
2  Christina 2001  5  3
3      Steve 2002  8  9
4      Diego 2003  7  6
5        Ali 2004  2  4
6       Brit 2005  1  1
7       Ruth 2006 10  9
8        Mia 2007  6  7
9      David 2008 10  9
10     Dylan 2009  3  2
```

I want to generate a data.frame `output` with all pair-wise combination of the rows in `df` that looks like this:

```
 >output
   name year v1 v2    name_2 year_2 v1_2 v2_2
1 Pablo 2000  2  9 Christina   2001    5    3
2 Pablo 2000  2  9     Steve   2002    8    9
3 Pablo 2000  2  9     Diego   2003    7    6
etc.
```

What are the fastest ways to do this?

Comment: Like `idx <- t(combn(seq_len(nrow(df)), 2));cbind(df[idx[,1],], df[idx[,2],])`?

Comment: `tidyr::crossing(df, df)`

Comment: @lukeA Indeed! But with different column names for the second series of variables. And the output as a data.frame.

Comment: @alistaire Right! But the first row contains a duplicate (i.e. Pablo-Pablo). Is it possible to generate this output without duplicates?

Comment: Use `cbind.data.frame` or wrap `as.data.frame` around it. After that, you can rename the columns by using `names(df)<-c("col1", "col2", .....)`

Comment: @lukeA Thank you! This works great on the sample. But on a larger subset of the real data, errors about size issues occur:"Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(seq_len(nrow(data1)), 2) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range"

Comment: I was thinking more about this today. Is this the precursor to leave-one-out cross validation? There are different ways to do LOOCV (some pre-coded), but perhaps the most similar approach here is to use `modelr::crossv_kfold(df, k = nrow(df))`, which uses `modelr`'s `resample` objects, which only store indices and a pointer to the data, which will hugely help the memory issue. You'll need to get comfortable with list columns, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tidyr::crossing` will return all combinations of observations, but you'll need to set names with `setNames` or the like. If you don't want self-matches, you can remove them by calling `dplyr::filter` on any unique ID column.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_crossed <- df %>% 
    setNames(paste0(names(.), '_2')) %>% 
    crossing(df) %>% 
    filter(name != name_2)

head(df_crossed)
##   name_2 year_2 v1_2 v2_2      name year v1 v2
## 1  Pablo   2000    5    5 Christina 2001  7  3
## 2  Pablo   2000    5    5     Steve 2002  1  9
## 3  Pablo   2000    5    5     Diego 2003  2  8
## 4  Pablo   2000    5    5       Ali 2004  9  5
## 5  Pablo   2000    5    5      Brit 2005  8  5
## 6  Pablo   2000    5    5      Ruth 2006  8  1
```

Another way to fix names would be to use `janitor::clean_names` after `crossing`, though it's an extra package.

Comment: Thanks Alistaire! This works great on smaller subsets of my data. But as soon as subsets get larger, R tries to allocate a vector of size 1338 GB... Not sure how to handle this :-)

Comment: Yeah, there's factorials in the number of rows required. It's also giving you both Pablo-Christina and Christina-Pablo, i.e. permutations, not combinations. Indexing with `combn` would allow a more limited set (if that's what you need), but it's still going to get really big really fast. You may not need to replicate your data, though; you can apply functions from one row onto others, and just store the results. Maybe a new question is in order.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will give the result the post owner was looking for.

```
name <- c("Pablo", "Christina", "Steve", "Diego", "Ali", "Brit", "Ruth", "Mia", "David", "Dylan")
year <- seq(2000, 2009, 1)
v1 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
v2 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(name, year, v1, v2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
print(df)
rows = nrow(df)
n <- rows * (rows - 1) / 2
ndf <- data.frame(
    name1=character(n),year1=numeric(n), v1_1=numeric(n),v2_1=numeric(n),
    name2=character(n),year2=numeric(n), v1_2=numeric(n),v2_2=numeric(n),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
k <- 1
for (i in 1:(rows-1))
{
    for (j in (i+1):rows)
    {
        ndf[k,] <- c(df[i,], df[j,])
        k <- k + 1
    }
}
print(ndf)

#        name year v1 v2
#1      Pablo 2000  4  9
#2  Christina 2001  2  1
#3      Steve 2002  2  9
#4      Diego 2003  5  5
#5        Ali 2004 10  4
#6       Brit 2005  5  2
#7       Ruth 2006  7 10
#8        Mia 2007  6  7
#9      David 2008  4 10
#10     Dylan 2009  7  3

#       name1 year1 v1_1 v2_1     name2 year2 v1_2 v2_2
#1      Pablo  2000    4    9 Christina  2001    2    1
#2      Pablo  2000    4    9     Steve  2002    2    9
#3      Pablo  2000    4    9     Diego  2003    5    5
#4      Pablo  2000    4    9       Ali  2004   10    4
#5      Pablo  2000    4    9      Brit  2005    5    2
#6      Pablo  2000    4    9      Ruth  2006    7   10
#7      Pablo  2000    4    9       Mia  2007    6    7
#8      Pablo  2000    4    9     David  2008    4   10
#9      Pablo  2000    4    9     Dylan  2009    7    3
#10 Christina  2001    2    1     Steve  2002    2    9
#...
```

Comment: this method doesn't include reciprocal duplicates, i.e. Christeina 2001 2 1 Pablo 2000 4 9 is not included.  To include reciprocals, both for loops need to go from 1:rows and in the inner loop to skip the cases where i == j. Of course the size of ndf needs to be recalculated also.

Answer (score 2):

Not to add to the noise but consider a base R cross join with `merge` on same dataframe that also filters out reverse duplicates. Do note, cross join before filter will return a 8 mill X 8 mill records dataset, so hopefully your RAM is sufficient for such an operation.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Pablo", "Christina", "Steve", "Diego", "Ali",
                          "Brit", "Ruth", "Mia", "David", "Dylan"), 
                 year = seq(2000, 2009, 1),
                 v1 =sample(1:10, 10, replace=T), 
                 v2 =sample(1:10, 10, replace=T),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# MERGE ON KEY, THEN REMOVE KEY COL
df$key <- 1
dfm <- merge(df, df, by="key")[,-1]   

# FILTER OUT SAME NAME AND REVERSE DUPS, THEN RENAME COLUMNS
dfm <- setNames(dfm[(dfm$name.x < dfm$name.y),], 
                c("name_p1", "year_p1", "V1_p1", "V2_p1",
                  "name_p2", "year_p2", "V1_p2", "V2_p2"))

# ALL PABLO PAIRINGS 
dfm[dfm$name_p1=='Pablo' | dfm$name_p2=='Pablo',]

#      name_p1 year_p1 V1_p1 V2_p1 name_p2 year_p2 V1_p2 V2_p2
# 3      Pablo    2000     7     8   Steve    2002     3     1
# 7      Pablo    2000     7     8    Ruth    2006     8     4
# 11 Christina    2001    10    10   Pablo    2000     7     8
# 31     Diego    2003     4     9   Pablo    2000     7     8
# 41       Ali    2004     5     3   Pablo    2000     7     8
# 51      Brit    2005     2     4   Pablo    2000     7     8
# 71       Mia    2007     7     7   Pablo    2000     7     8
# 81     David    2008     1     7   Pablo    2000     7     8
# 91     Dylan    2009     9     2   Pablo    2000     7     8
```

*If somehow this large set derived from an SQL compliant database, I can provide the counterpart in SQL which may be more efficient as the filter runs with join process and not separately after.*

Answer (score 1):

You could cross join the name column to itself, using `data.table` and remove repeated cases.  This will result in a smaller structure on which to merge in data rather than doing the full merge, then filtering.  You can add the rest of the data with two merges: once to merge data associated with the first name column and again to merge in data associated with the second column.

```
name <- c("Pablo", "Christina", "Steve", "Diego", "Ali", "Brit", "Ruth", "Mia", "David", "Dylan")
year <- seq(2000, 2009, 1)
v1 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
v2 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
# stringsAsFactors = FALSE in order for pmin to work properly
df <- data.frame(name, year, v1, v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkey(df)

# cross-join name column to itself while removing duplicates and redundancies
name_cj <- setnames(
  CJ(df[, name], df[, name])[V1 < V2], # taking a hint from Parfait's clever solution
  c("name1", "name2"))

# perform 2 merges, once for the 1st name column and
# again for the 2nd name colum
name_cj <- merge(
  merge(name_cj, df, by.x = "name1", by.y = "name"),
  df,
  by.x = "name2", by.y = "name", suffixes = c("_1", "_2"))

# reorder columns as desired with setorder()
head(name_cj)
#      name2     name1 year_1 v1_1 v2_1 year_2 v1_2 v2_2
#1:      Brit       Ali   2004    3    8   2005    4    5
#2: Christina       Ali   2004    3    8   2001    9    8
#3: Christina      Brit   2005    4    5   2001    9    8
#4:     David       Ali   2004    3    8   2008    5    2
#5:     David      Brit   2005    4    5   2008    5    2
#6:     David Christina   2001    9    8   2008    5    2
```

Answer (score 1):

This extension of @alistaires solution shows a crossed matrix used as index. The question as stated wants the full crossed output which
will be very large (~64 million rows for 8 million items) so there 
is really no way around the memory requirement. However, if the
the real-world use of this is to deal with subsets, the indexing technique
shown here may be a way to reduce memory use. Its possible that crossing the integers only uses less memory during the crossing operation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossed <- as.matrix(crossing(1:nrow(df), 1:nrow(df)))
# bind and name in one step (may be inefficient) so that filter can be applied in one step
output <- as.data.frame(cbind(df[crossed[, 1],], 
                              data.frame(name_2 = df[crossed[, 2], 1],
                                         year_2 = df[crossed[, 2], 2],
                                         v1_2   = df[crossed[, 2], 3],
                                         v2_2   = df[crossed[, 2], 4]) )) %>%
           filter(!(name == name_2 & year == year_2))

# estimated sized for 8 million rows gine this 10 row sample
format(object.size(output) / (10 / 8e6), units="MB")
#[1] "5304 Mb"
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` is a bad habit that frequently causes type problems. Just use `data.frame`.